# Make many populate in deep populate, 2nd level

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am doing a query of nested objects using populate and when wanting to access a population of the second level, it does not recognize me if not the last population

I'm working under nodejs and mongodb, using the mongoose library

For the population of 'tours_favoritos' only recognizes me the last: 'guia' with its population of 'idiomas'. I do not populate 'sitios', nor 'turistas', nor 'categoria', nor 'empresa_turismo'. If I change the order of the population, only the last one populates me.

```
servicev1.addGustoFavorito = function (id_turista, id_gusto) {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    GustoTurista.findById(id_gusto, function (error, gusto) {
        if (!error) {
            var query = Turista.findByIdAndUpdate(id_turista, { $push: { gustos: gusto._id } }, { new: true });
            query.
                populate({
                    path: 'empresas_favoritas', model: EmpresaTurismo
                }).
                populate({
                    path: 'tours_favoritos',
                    model: Tour,
                    populate: { path: 'sitios', model: Sitio },
                    populate: { path: 'turistas', model: Turista },
                    populate: { path: 'categoria', model: CategoriaTour },
                    populate: { path: 'empresa_turismo', model: EmpresaTurismo },
                    populate: {
                        path: 'guia', model: Guia,
                        populate: { path: 'idiomas', model: Idioma }
                    }
                }).
                populate({
                    path: 'gustos', model: GustoTurista
                })
                .exec(function (err, success) {
                    if (err) {
                        return reject(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        return resolve(success);
                    }
                })
        } else {
            return reject(error);
        }
    })
})
```

}

[See code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74E6l.png)

Comment: The problem here is that without any knowledge of how the models actually interrelate and what the expected result would be we cannot determine what would be wrong with what you are doing. You would basically need to show sample data from each model that would be expected to be retrieved by all of the `populate()` calls. The *real big problem* here though is that's ***a lot of joins*** and MongoDB just is not designed to be used like that. Furthermore you probably do not realize that every time you type `populate` that is effectively another query to the server. I count **11 requests** here.

Comment: Basically **11 requests** to the server ( each `findBy` and every mention on `populate` ) just to return some data on a page is **extremely excessive** and will cause major performance problems for you ongoing. You really need to redesign this since you are still thinking far too much in relational terms. [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) can help by making that **one request**, but the "joins" are still a significant overhead here.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake here is in this second `populate` query:

```
.populate({
    path: 'tours_favoritos',
    model: Tour,
    populate: { path: 'sitios', model: Sitio },
    populate: { path: 'turistas', model: Turista },
    populate: { path: 'categoria', model: CategoriaTour },
    populate: { path: 'empresa_turismo', model: EmpresaTurismo },
    populate: {
        path: 'guia', model: Guia,
        populate: { path: 'idiomas', model: Idioma }
    }
})
```

You are passing an object to populate function, and everytime you are using another populate inside that object, it overrides the old one, it is similar to any object definition.

Eg:

```
var a={
  foo : "bar",
  foo : "bar2",
  foo : "bar3"
}

//the last foo overrides the first two
//a.foo = bar3
```

just like above example, last populate is overriding the previous populates.

Now back to solve your question,

You need to pass array to `populate` field, so that it populates all the given fields you want

**Try this:**

```
.populate({
    path: 'tours_favoritos',
    model: Tour,
    populate: [
        { path: 'sitios', model: Sitio },
        { path: 'turistas', model: Turista },
        { path: 'categoria', model: CategoriaTour },
        { path: 'empresa_turismo', model: EmpresaTurismo },
        {
            path: 'guia', model: Guia,
            populate: { path: 'idiomas', model: Idioma }
        }
    ]
})
```

replace the above code in place of your second populate query and it will work.